# how to share a common data structure in high performance java web service applications

Tags: java, database, web-services, shared-memory

I am developing a couple of web services - one to BUY a product and another to VALIDATE a product. Multiple clients will be calling the BUY (around 250/sec) and same for VALIDATE. 
They need to query and update a tabular data structure before calling the backend.

I have a feeling that using a relational database table like Oracle to maintain this common data structure will slow down things because of network latency (assuming database and queries are tuned optimally). I have been proposed EhCache and Hazelcast but I prefer using a database table because I know it better.

**Can anyone confirm if hitting a database across a network could prove to be a bottleneck for an application that's supposed to serve 250-300 transactions per second?**

Certainly we are okay if the server instance goes down and we lose the in-memory representation of the data structure.

Comment: are you aware that your cache will work just for query requests? For update you will need to execute database update + cache invalidation... what is the proportion of queries request X update requests?

Comment: it will be one to one ratio.. each call will read and possibly update as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, caching will help just if the update requests is lower than the query request... imagine you cache as a big map that will store values already queried if you update every time rows on server you need to update the too, and you update the cache by invalidating its entry in order to perform request to the DB again.

Comment: let us forget the database option for a moment, and if I am updating the cache frequently then the whole point of using the cache invalidated - right ? 

Is there some shared data structure hosted by the app server that I can use (it does not have to be backed by the database because we don't care about persisting the data structure in this case) I will be using glass fish or jboss. 

The whole reason of this discussion is I cann't have a datastructure as an instance variable in the web service because (a) its not thread-safe and (b) cannot be shared between multiple web service requests

Comment: you don't need the data persisted? but how long want you retain the data on your server?

Comment: for now, we want to go with something that's fast in-memory solution, later we can go with some distributed cache like hazelcast that will sync between nodes. but for now we want to bring up one node serving 250 transactions per second and we think a remote database over a network might be a bottleneck.

Comment: ok, in this case I don't see any problem... I mean, you just need to configure the cache so that the maximum amount of memory is not bigger that the space you have from heap, and this you can configure on ehcache.

Comment: If you don't want to use a relational database, use a cache system like EhCache for your needs **or** use a NoSQL database engine like [Big Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)

Comment: so you can lookup the ehcache in some kind of JNDI space so its a shared resource visible to all web services in your container ? and Does it support a tabular datastructure with multiple columns .. (because sometime cache solutions only allow Maps to be cached - i am new to the cache stuff so please bear with me on this question)

Comment: another concern is if I store the tabular data structure (using java 2 array for example) in cache (instead of database table) - how fast can i search it for entries in different columns, all of a sudden i am missing the SQL capabilities of searching a 5000 row table in milliseconds. Am i correct in this assumption or can you suggest something regarding this as well.  thanks for your help so far.

Comment: one thing per time... 1. JNDI is a bit different, the cache will be a kind of big map for you a key to some values; 2. cache will cache your data structure, if you can model your information in classes and instance it into objects it an be cached; if you want search you need to implement it by yourself, take a bit of time to check in memory databases such as Apache-Derby or HSQLDB (so you have all in memory plus power of query language to perform your search), or even the NoSQL dbs as commented by Luiggi

Answer (score 1):

That really depends what your application is doing. 
Of course you can use a database machine with expensive hardware, and expensive network hardware. 
The question is - is this really needed? 
As stated in some of the comments - Caching will mostly help you in case that you perform mostly READ (more READ requests than write requests).
In order to optimize you should consider indexing  (for example - if you store addressed, you can consider indexing by an "ip" field, assuming that most queries that are not by ID are by this field) , 
which is just one part of correct DB schema planning (other aspects of this may be to avoid complex joins between tables, by modelling your data properly as much as possible), and maybe even a NoSQL database. 
What about scaling You should use a distributed cache/distibuted data structure if you go for caching and scaling. 
For example, [infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/) can help here. 
You can also improve performance by using in memory/in process (i.e - its code is in a jar and is co-hosted on the JVM of the application) such as [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) - this can further reduce querying time.
But once again, it really depends on your specific use cases, what you described is unfortunately too general.

Comment: Details -our web services are going to call some legacy platforms and because of some design constraints in those legacy platforms the web services will need to have a device handle before they can call the legacy platform. These device handles (like ip addresses) will be stored in a table on application startup (there are only limited number of them like 1000). Then when every request from the web goes to hit the web service, it has reserve the spot by obtaining a free device handle and then call the legacy platform. So every web service request will first READ, then (if spot available) WRITE

Comment: so the WRITE and READ will ratio is pretty much 1 (equal number of read and writes). And for now we don't want to build something that is distributed (because of the time constraints). So I am inclining towards in-memory database, its fast (because its in-memory) and its relational so its searchable using SQL. I THINK that will serve us for now. Plus it will avoid the hassle of acquiring a new product as well.

Comment: I have provided some more details as requested by you. May be you can give me some more detailed advice based on this info.

Comment: I will modify my answer accordingly